# How to define a parameter with optional value?

Tags: string, powershell, parameters, return-value

I'm trying to create a function with a parameter (Para2) of type string, and  value ("ABC") assigned. That value should be used, when only the paramter has been called. And if a value comes with the parameter, the value should be used instead.
But I don't know how to do. I stuck, and need your help please.

I played with AllowEmptyString and different ValidationSets, but was not successfully. This is what I have so far:

```
Function MyFunction {

    [CmdletBinding (
        PositionalBinding = $false,
        DefaultParameterSetName = "MySet1"
    )]

    Param (

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "MySet1")]
        [string]$Para1 = "Para1 default",

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "MySet1")]
        [string]$Para2 = "ABC"

    )

    Write-Output $Para2

}

MyFunction -Para2 "xxx"
```

Calling the function like 'MyFunction -Para2 "xxx"' retruns "xxx" - that's expected.
I like to find a way to call the function like 'MyFunction -Para2', and want to see "ABC" as return value.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just call it without any parameters..

Comment: By adding the '-Para2' to your call, you're telling PowerShell that you're going to supply the value. Call it without parameters to use the default values ("Para1 default" and "ABC")

Answer (score 0):

You can do what TheIncorrigle1 says, but if the input variable might be empty you could also use the following:

```
function MyFunction{
    [CmdletBinding(
        PositionalBinding = $false,
        DefaultParameterSetName = "MySet1"  
    )]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "MySet1")]
        [string]$Para1 = "Para1 default",

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "MySet1")]
        [string]$Para2 = $para2
    )
    if(!$Para2){
        Write-Output "ABC"
    }else{
        Write-Output $Para2
    }
}

MyFunction -Para2 ""
```

This way if something is put after -Para2 it will be the output and if the input is empty or $null it outputs "ABC".

Also I formatted the script a little bit to make it more readable. A little piece of advise is the PowerShell Scripting Guide to always ensure your scripts to be readable and maintainable.

Hope this helps!

Possible solution for your question from comment:

```
try{
    MyFunction -Para2
}catch{
    MyFunction -Para2 ""
}
```

Comment: Hm, ok, I see. Thank you so much. That could be a workaround. But the big goal is to use -Para2 without "". Any chance to reach this? Any chance to automatically extend Para2 with "" when its typed without?

Comment: @Schiroky What's the purpose here? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have no clue why you would want this, but I've added a possible solution in my answer above

Comment: As Mathias is asking, it would be really helpful to explain exactly what you want to achieve and why.

Comment: The plan would be to call the function with a parameter, and when no value comes with the parameter, just use a default. If the parameter comes with a value, use the value. That's the plan. I do read that this might be not possible. I'll go for the workaround. Thank you guys.